# Vue3 event argument in emit from child component returns undefined in parent

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, arguments, vuejs3

I am attempting to emit a value with an event in a child component that gets used in the parent as per the vue [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#event-arguments), but the value (selectedItem) returns 'undefined' in the parent when I try console logging it from the function.

How can I properly send over the selectedItem value from the child component to get used in the parent?

Relevant code below.

Child Component:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {
    props: {
        inventory: Object
    },
    setup(props) {
        const selectedItem = ref("");
        function showInventoryItem(item) {
            for (let i = 0; i < props.inventory.length; i++) {
                if (props.inventory[i].id == item.id){
                    this.selectedItem = item.id;               
                }
            }
        }
        return {
            selectedItem,
        }
    },
    template: `
      <div id="inventory-bar">
        <h3>Inventory</h3>
        <div id="inventory-grid">
            <button v-for="item in inventory" class="grid-item" @click="showInventoryItem(item)">
                {{item.label}}
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="item-info" v-show="selectedItem">
            <button @click="$emit('useItem', selectedItem)">Use item</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  `
}
```

Parent:

```
<script type="module">
    import { createApp } from 'vue'

    createApp({
        components: {
        },
        setup() {
     
            function useItem(selectedItem) {
                console.log("selectedItem:" + selectedItem);
            }
            return {
                useItem
            }
        }
    }).mount('#app')
</script>
<div id="app">
    <inventory-bar :inventory="inventory" @use-item="useItem(selectedItem)"></inventory-bar>
</div>
```

Comment: You are logging a variable called `item`. Try changing it to `selectedItem`

Comment: That was a mistake from copying my code over, I have updated the example but selectedItem is still undefined in the code.

Comment: Try with `@use-item="useItem"`, removing the `(selectedItem)`.